# Cannot access page clicking <Link> instead reloads page Remix Js

Tags: typescript, logging, error-handling, react-router, remix.run

I'm having a small problem with the navigation bar in my remix Js app. Whenever I want to click on the button to "Mon compte" the page reloads and i cannot access the page. No errors, nothing plus i recently installed the remix devtools, and the plugin dissapears when i'm on the page ? Am I missing something that is important to know ?

Here's my root.tsx :

```
import type { LinksFunction, MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import {Links,Link, LiveReload,Outlet,Meta,Scripts, ScrollRestoration,useLoaderData, useActionData} from "@remix-run/react";
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';
import { SpeedInsights } from "@vercel/speed-insights/remix"
import {auth} from '~/firebase/firebase_init'
import { LoaderFunction, ActionFunction, json } from "@remix-run/node";

import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { destroyUserSession, getUserSession } from "./utils/session.server";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import Navbar from './component/navbar';
import Footer from './component/footer';
/* CSS IMPORTS GLOBAL*/
import global from "./styles/global.css";
/* CSS IMPORTS NAVBAR*/
import navbartel from "./styles/navbar-tel.css";
import navbarpc from "./styles/navbar-pc.css";
import navbartab from "./styles/navbar-tab.css";
import icon from "../public/favicon.ico"
/* CSS IMPORTS FOOTER*/
import footerpc from "./styles/footer-pc.css";
import rdtStylesheet from "remix-development-tools/index.css"; 

import pnglandingog from "../public/FALC'On_landing_page_og.png"
export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  {rel: "stylesheet", href: global},
  {rel: "stylesheet", href: navbartel, media: "screen and (max-width: 999px)",},
  {rel: "stylesheet", href: navbartab, media: "screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1399px)",},
  {rel: "stylesheet", href: navbarpc, media: "screen and (min-width: 1400px)",},
  {rel: "stylesheet", href: footerpc,},
  ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: rdtStylesheet }] : []),
];

function App() {
  const isAuthenticated  = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
       //Meta links here
      </head>
      <body>
        <Navbar isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer/>
        <Scripts />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Analytics/>
        <LiveReload />
        <SpeedInsights />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  let isAuthenticated = false;
  const session = await getUserSession(request);
    //console.log("SESSION", session);
    const userId = session.get("userId");
    console.log("USER ID", userId);
    if (userId) {
      isAuthenticated = true;
    }
  return isAuthenticated;
};

//Dev tools importation
let AppExport = App;
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { 
  const { withDevTools } = await import("remix-development-tools"); 
   AppExport = withDevTools(AppExport);
   console.log("DEVTOOLS IMPORTED");
}
export default AppExport;
```

This is the navbar:

```
import {  useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import Logo from '../../public/Logo-FALCON.png';
import { Form } from '@remix-run/react';

export default function Navbar({isAuthenticated}: {isAuthenticated: boolean}) {

  console.log('isAuthenticated in navbar', isAuthenticated)
  const location = useLocation();
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    console.log ('toggleMenu');
    setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  };

const handleLinkClick=()=>{
    console.log('handleLinkClick!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    setIsMenuOpen(false);
  }
  
  
  return (
    <header>
      
      <div className="nav-logo">
        <Link to="/">
          <img src={Logo} alt="logo" width="110" height="102" /> 
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <h1>FALC'On</h1>
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="nav-burgerlabelb" onClick={toggleMenu}>
      <label htmlFor="toggle">
        <button>☰</button>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked={isMenuOpen} readOnly />
      </label>
</div>

      {/*-----------------------------------USUAL LINKS NAVBAR MENU HERE-----------------------------------*/}
      <nav className="nav-links">
        <h2>
            <Link to="/" className={location.pathname === '/' || location.pathname === '/traduction-document' ? 'active-link' : ''}>
            Traduction
          </Link>
        </h2>
       
        <h2>
          <Link to="/a-propos" className={location.pathname === '/a-propos' ? 'active-link' : ''}>
            A propos
          </Link>
        </h2>
        
        <h2>
        <Link to="/a-propos#equipe" className={location.pathname === '/a-propos#equipe' ? 'active-link' : ''}>
            Notre équipe
          </Link>
        </h2>
      
        <h2>
          <Link to="/contact" onClick={handleLinkClick} className={location.pathname === '/contact' ? 'active-link' : ''}>
            Nous contacter
          </Link>
        
        </h2>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <>
            <div className="account-dropdown">
              <button className='account-button'>Mon compte</button>
              <div className="dropdown-content">
                <Link to="/profil" onClick={handleLinkClick}>Profil</Link>
                <Link to="/historique" onClick={handleLinkClick}>Historique</Link>
                  <div className='logout-navbarpc'>
                    <form method='post' action='/logout'>
                      <button type='submit'>Déconnexion</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className='on-account'>
              <Link to="/login"  onClick={handleLinkClick}>
                  <button className='account-button'>Mon compte</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </nav>
        //continuation of the navbar but for burger menu
</header>
```

And finally the login.tsx:

```
import { ActionFunction, LinksFunction, LoaderFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { useLoaderData, useActionData ,useFetcher, useSubmit } from "@remix-run/react";
import { json, redirect, createCookieSessionStorage } from "@remix-run/node";

import { useEffect, useState, useRef,  } from 'react';
import { Link } from "@remix-run/react";
import { Form } from '@remix-run/react';
import { getSession, getUserSession, createUserSession, requireUser } from "~/utils/session.server";
import loginstyle from "~/styles/login-style.css";
import { AuthorizationError } from 'remix-auth';
import { auth } from "~/firebase/firebase_init";
import {connectAuthEmulator,createUserWithEmailAndPassword,getAuth,onAuthStateChanged,sendEmailVerification,sendPasswordResetEmail,signInWithEmailAndPassword,signOut} from 'firebase/auth';

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
    { rel: "stylesheet", href: loginstyle},
];
export const config = {
  memory:2048,
  maxDuration: 300,
};
  
export default function Login() {
  const loaderDta = useLoaderData();
  console.log("(LOGIN.TSX) LOADER DATA ", loaderDta);
  console.log("(LOGIN.TSX) RENDER FUNCTION ")
  const actionData = useActionData();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const fetcher = useFetcher();
  const isSubmitting = fetcher.state === "submitting";
  const handleEmailChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="login-title"><h1>Se connecter</h1></div>
      <Form method="post" action="/login"> 
        <input
          className="Email"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Adresse mail"
          required
          value={email}
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
        />
        <input
          className="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Mot de passe"
          autoComplete="current-password"
          required
          value={password}
          onChange={handlePasswordChange}
        />
        {actionData?.errorCode && (
          <p>
            <em>Login failed: {actionData.errorMessage}</em>
          </p>
        )}
        <div className='redirection-mdp-oublie'>
          <Link to="/oubli-mdp"><h2>Mot de passe oublié</h2></Link>
      </div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} className='button'>Login</button>
      </Form>
      
      <div className='redirection-register'>
          <Link to="/register"><h2>Pas encore inscrit ?</h2></Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  console.log("(login.tsx) Action function triggered");
  try {
      const formData = await request.formData();
      const email = formData.get('email');
      const password = formData.get('password');
       // Validate inputs
       if (!email || !password) {
          
          throw json(
            {
              errorCode : 'login',
              errorMessage : 'Email et mot de passe sont requis'
            },
            { status:400}
          );
          
       }
       if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { 
        if (!auth.emulatorConfig) {
          connectAuthEmulator(auth, '127.0.0.1:9099');
          console.log("EMULATOR CONNECTED");
        }
      }
      console.log("EMAIL", email);
      console.log("PASSWORD", password);
      const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.toString(), password.toString());
      const userEmail = auth.currentUser;
      console.log("USER EMAIL", userEmail);
      if (userEmail && userEmail.emailVerified) {
        const idToken = await user.getIdToken(true);
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('idToken', idToken);
        console.log("SUBMIT");
        console.log("AUTH.SERVER --- createUserSession TRIGGERED");
        return await createUserSession( idToken , "/");
      } else {
        console.log("EMAIL NOT VERIFIED");
        return json(
          {
            errorCode : 'login',
            errorMessage : 'Votre email n\'a pas été vérifié. Veuillez vérifier votre boîte mail.'
          },
          { status:401}
        );
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("AUTH.SERVER --- ACTION ERROR TRIGGERED");
      return json(
        {
          errorCode : 'login',
          errorMessage : 'Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer.'
        },
        { status:500}
      );
  }
};

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
    let isAuthenticated = true;
    console.log("(LOGIN.TSX) LOADER FUNCTION ")
    const session = await getUserSession(request);
    const userId = session.get("userId");
    console.log("USER ID", userId); 
    if (userId) {
        return redirect("/profil");
    } else {
        
        return isAuthenticated;
    }
  };
```

I know this is a lot of code but really i can't seem to find an answer anywhere...

I know this is a lot of code but really i can't seem to find an answer anywhere... I did try to change the parameters of the deployment (export config) but nothing changed. It only works when the actionfunction is erased... And i don't know why this is happening... Because it worked well this week, I only changed the config for the maxduration and the memory this week but except this, nothing. I tried the library react-router-dom but no success.

I can give you the logs of the navigation :
`` `(root.tsx)USER ID undefined ``
`(_index.tsx)USER ID undefined`
`isAuthenticated in navbar false`
`IS AUTHENTICATED false`
`GET / 200 - - 55.301 ms`
`(LOGIN.TSX) LOADER FUNCTION` 
`(login.tsx)USER ID undefined`
`GET /login?_data=routes%2Flogin 200 - - 7.542 ms`
`(root.tsx)USER ID undefined`
`(_index.tsx)USER ID undefined`
`isAuthenticated in navbar false`
`IS AUTHENTICATED false`
`GET / 200 - - 17.393 ms`

So as you can see the loader function of login.tsx is executed but nothing is rendered and it reloads the page after the 'GET /login...' Plus the handleLinkClick is not triggered because nothing is being printed in the console.

So yeah it's been 3 days now and no solution at the horizon

Comment: The "Mon compte" button has `type="submit"` attribute by default, is there a `form` wrapping this code higher up the ReactTree? Try adding `type="button"` attribute if this button isn't supposed to submit any form.